# Specific Regex task:

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have List of 30000+ strings from Dictionary and have to find Matches.

(I have to find all words which matches with numbers from 0 to 1000 and... every digit is represent by letters)

```
vowelsAndH = {a,á,e,é,ě,i,í,o,ó,u,ú,ů,y,ý,h}; 
one = {t,d,ť,ď};
two = {n,ň};
...
```

for exam number 121:

```
{vowelsAndH+}{one}{vowelsAndH+}{two}{vowelsAndH+}{one}{vowelsAndH+}

word "eděnautin" is Matched for 121
word "dnautin" is Matched for 121
word "dnaunin" is not Matched for 121, but is Matched for 122
```

So Question is, how to get this

```
{vowelsAndH+}{one}{vowelsAndH+}{two}{vowelsAndH+}{one}{vowelsAndH+}
```

to regex format.

Comment: Is `vowelsAndH` a required separator between digits or simply characters to be disregarded?  What number would "dtnt" be, if any?

Answer (score 0):

I see it in this way:

1. You're dumping all symbols defining digits into one OR match (for 1 and 2: [tdťďnň])
2. After you receive results your doing `switch` on matches and find out which digit matched letter belongs to

Possible regex:

```
    [aáeéěiíoóuúůyýh]*(?:([tdťďnň])[aáeéěiíoóuúůyýh]*)+
```

Comment: I would be enough if I know how to create regex for one number (for exam 121), then I can create regex for any number programmatically.

Comment: This approach going to fit any number from 0 to infinity (except the empty string). What's the problem?

Comment: Probably I have asked wrong question - I have to put this {vowelsAndH+}{one}{vowelsAndH+}{two}{vowelsAndH+}{one}{vowelsAndH+} to regex format.